# .net 6 DI ApplicationServices not contains in WebApplication

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-localization

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
```

I want to globalization in my project using .net 6. However in `program.cs` I get an error

> Error CS1061
> 'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationServices' and no accessible extension method 'ApplicationServices' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What can I do?

Comment: Your `Configure` method does not run in the context of a request (it happens during startup) so there is no point in trying to get an `IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>` there. (But you _can_ use it inside a middleware func, of course).

Answer (score 15):

In the .Net 6 `ApplicationServices` are accessible as the `app.Services` which returns `IServiceProvider`. You can try like this.

```
var options = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

Comment: For .Net 7 is the same

Answer (score 11):

app should be casted into an interface as shown below:-

```
var options = ((IApplicationBuilder)app).ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

Comment: You can also just directly call [app.Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication.services). It's the same service provider.

Comment: @Ber'Zophus you should submit your response as an answer. That worked great for me.